# Как кнопке открыть задать чтобы открывал проводник с файлами, как например в ворде

Tags: c++, gui

Всем привет!

не могу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "Открыть" в окне унификации, открывался проводник, чтобы можно было выбрать путь и открыть файл, как это реализовано в других программах. Искал на английском, папку проводник перевел как Explorer folder, но там все результаты с браузером. Я уже начал просто ранее созданное окно с названием Explorer открывать, получается, но не то что нужно. [image: Окно унификации]

Comment: [getopenfilename](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getopenfilenamea)?

Comment: `IFileOpenDialog`